# Getting a 2x2 facet_grid with varying scales

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data in a nice format which I would ideally like to plot on a 2x2 frame, each individual plot having it's own X and Y scales. Here's the code I am using as of now:

```
    p <- ggplot(data=temp,aes(x=variable,y=value,group=custno,color=cluster)) + 
      geom_path(alpha=0.4) +
      theme_bw() + 
      theme(legend.title=element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_text(hjust=0, angle=0), 
            axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=1, angle=45),plot.title=element_text(size=20)) +
      ylab('Revenue') +
      xlab('') + ggtitle('') +
      scale_color_manual(values=c('#66c2a5','#fc8d62','#8da0cb','#e78ac3')) + 
      facet_grid(.~cluster,scales='free',space='free')
    p
```

Here's the plot that I get:

[image]

I want to have a 2x2 grid with separate scales, so that category `3` is a little more glorified and the differences more pronounced.

Here's the sample data

```
custno variable value cluster
100 Month1  169.15  3
250 Month1  4012.15 1
303 Month1  2731.08 1
312 Month1  890.40  2
337 Month1  1133.40 3
100 Month2  169.15  3
250 Month2  4012.15 1
303 Month2  2731.08 1
312 Month2  890.40  2
337 Month2  1133.40 3
100 Month3  169.15  3
250 Month3  4012.15 1
303 Month3  2731.08 1
312 Month3  890.40  2
337 Month3  1133.40 3
100 Month4  169.15  3
250 Month4  4012.15 1
303 Month4  2731.08 1
312 Month4  890.40  2
337 Month4  1133.40 3
100 Month5  169.15  3
250 Month5  4012.15 1
303 Month5  2731.08 1
312 Month5  890.40  2
337 Month5  1133.40 3
100 Month6  169.15  3
250 Month6  4012.15 1
303 Month6  2731.08 1
312 Month6  890.40  2
337 Month6  1133.40 3
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to replace

```
facet_grid(.~cluster,scales='free',space='free')
```

With

```
facet_wrap(~ cluster, scales = 'free', space = 'free', nrow = 2)
```

The difference between `facet_wrap` and `facet_grid` is that facet wrap can do a "line break" within a single variable. `facet_grid` is really made for a grid of plots with one (or more) variables defining the columns and different variable(s) defining the rows, so such line breaks don't make sense.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but getting the following error: `Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) : 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting`

Comment: posted some sample data

Comment: yep the `.` fixed it. Thanks a lot guys.